# "PYTHONPATH", going through the list and check elements

Tags: python, list, if-statement, pythonpath, statements

i have to set my variable

```
maya_env_variable = "PYTHONPATH"
```

after i have to set a new path

```
new_path_list ['User/Desktop']
```

i have to get the current value of my `PYTHONPATH` using `os.environ['PYTHONPATH']`

```
current_path_string = os.environ ['PYTHONPATH']
```

If you're in windows , use `;` to separate the paths
Elif you're in mac or linux , use : to separate the paths

```
current_path_list = current_path_string.split()
```

i've done until here but 
now i have to go through each path in my new path list
and check if the that path is already in my current path list...
If it is not, add it to the current_path_list
,,, this the part i really don't understand

Comment: yes. 
i didn't understand how to do the last part ..

Comment: Please be more specific — I also don't understand what is the question..